# Control order views are considered for display based on contextual filters

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two different views being used to show two different types of content.

One is a view to show a taxonomy term and it has a path like this:
/foo/faa/%   with % being for the term placeholder

The other view shows a node and has two conditional placeholders (the first placeholder is the term the node is tagged with and the second is the alias for the node):
/foo/faa/%/%

Drupal is trying to show the term on the node view instead of the term view. Is there a way to get Drupal to only use the term view for terms and the node views for the other?

Comment: It seems as if you're missing validation on your Contextual filters. Turn it on on all your Contextual filters and you'll see options which types of content to display the results on.